# Copy item and add it to list based on chance

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, append

The function reproduce takes 3 arguments:
viruses( a list of viruses). mutationProb(float 0-1 chance to mutate only when reproducing) and reproductionProb(float 0-1 chance to reproduce). So a float of 0.2, 0.4 would give it a 40% to reproduce, and if it reproduces a 20% chance to mutate.

I already wrote the mutate function, it works correctly :

```
def mutate(virus):
    # choose random index to change
    index = random.randint(0, len(virus) - 1)

    # make sure you are not using the previous char by removing it from 
    # the mutations to choose from
    mutations = [i for i in 'ATCG' if i != virus[index]]

    # swap out the char at index with a random mutation
    return virus[:index] + random.choice(mutations) + virus[index+1:]
```

but my reproduce won't add the new viruses to the list if a virus reproduces ( based on reproductionProb), the new virus should be added to the already existing list of viruses,mutated or not,( mutate based on mutationProb ).

Each virus has an individual chance to reproduce

```
def reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb):
    for virus in viruses:
        if random.random() < reproductionProb:
            if random.random() < mutationProb:
                mutate(virus)
                viruses.append(virus)
            else:
                viruses.append(virus)
    return viruses
```

Anyone got any idea on why my function doesn't do that already? As I see it it append the mutated virus based on the mutationProb, else it appends it without mutating.

Comment: Since both the appends rely on `random.random() < reproductionProb` being true, I'd verify that that condition is evaluating as you expect.

Comment: yes, it can only mutate if it is reproducing

Comment: post sample input and expected output.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul input lit of viruses [ATCG, GATC] 1.0, 1.0: OUTPUT: [ATCG, GATC, TTCG, GAGC]

Answer (score 1):

As Carcigenicate said, you want to make sure the `random.random() < reproductionProb` is evaluating to true as you would expect i.e. 4 in 10 times (or whatever).

As far as your code goes, if you always want to make a copy of the virus if it meets the reproduction criteria (40% chance) and then only mutate as well it if it meets the mutation criteria (20% chance), then you could simplify your code a little.

```
def reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb):
for virus in viruses:

    if random.random() < reproductionProb:
        if random.random() < mutationProb:
            mutate(virus)

        viruses.append(virus)

return viruses
```

Comment: yes! I had that originally but I changed it since it didnt work aswell